# Updating Rows In a Table That Was Used to Import From SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package

I am currenly creating a SSIS package that selects the top 2000 entries from one table and insert those entries into another table.  How can I update those entries in the original table (my select contains a condition whereby I check where the status is still empty) so in my next run of the SSIS package they won't be imported?

**EDIT
As I can't give the DLL due to security reasons, to sketch my scenario, I have TableA and TableB who share the same structure:

- Index Number (Primary Key, Indexed, Auto Increment)
- Name (varchar)
- Surname (varchar)
- Status (varchar)
- Type (varchar)
- Import Date (date)

Using an OLE DB Source within my Data Flow Task, the following query is used to determine which cases I should import from TableA to TableB (an OLE DB Destination):

```
SELECT TOP(2000) * 
FROM TableA 
 WHERE Status = '' 
  AND [Type] = 'New Case' 
ORDER BY IndexNumber ASC
```

Now those cases imported from TableA to TableB, I want to update the cases in Table A to not import them again.  The data in TableB is often moved to another database, so I can't use that for comparison.

Comment: Please supply the DDL as well as some sample data for each table. What you want to do will be difficult without some sort of identifier on the tables.

Comment: Do you need confirm that they made it all of the way through the SSIS pipeline or just mark them that they were picked up?

Comment: I just want to add some sort of update to mark the rows that were picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use this pattern:

1. FIRST update the source table and mark 1000 records as 'ready to extract', i.e. set them to 1
2. Next, select all records from your source table that are ready to extract
3. Lastly, if the extract was succesful, update the 1's (ready to extract) to 2's (extracted OK)

Comment: summerpet39 and Nepali Rookie's answers also helped a lot, but building my package according to your suggestion worked perfectly (just tried a small sample of 10 records).  The design is very simple and works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

I would add a `Execute SQL Task` at the end of the control flow to update these first 2000 records in your original table to some other status (status = 3 or something). That way, since you already have a null check in your query, it would not select those initial 2000 records in your next run.

Comment: If I do it like this, to ensure that the correct first 2000 were updated, would it be wise to add an order by statement to ensure that the exact rows are updated?

Comment: Yeah, you could set those records to a different status like @Nick.McDermaid suggested. And, then update their status again at the end of the process.